# DirectoryEntry "The server is not operational" trying to query remote server

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, directoryservices

I am trying to query a remote Active Directory server that requires a VPN connection be established (in order to access the server). Below is the snippet of my code:

```
DirectoryEntry adsEntry = new DirectoryEntry();
adsEntry.Username = "user_name";
adsEntry.Password = "password";
adsEntry.AuthenticationType = AuthenticationTypes.Secure;
adsEntry.Path = "LDAP://domain.com:636/CN=John Doe,DC=staff,DC=com";

DirectorySearcher adsSearcher = new DirectorySearcher(adsEntry);
adsSearcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("cn");

try
{
    SearchResult adsSearchResult = adsSearcher.FindOne();
    <p>cn: @adsSearchResult.Properties["cn"][0].ToString()</p>
    adsEntry.Close();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    adsEntry.Close();
}
```

And the exception:

> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x8007203A): The server
>   is not operational. at
>   System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry.Bind(Boolean throwIfFail) at
>   System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry.Bind() at
>   System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry.get_AdsObject() at
>   System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher.FindAll(Boolean
>   findMoreThanOne) at
>   System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher.FindOne() at
>   ASP._Page_Views_AD_cshtml.Execute() in line 37

I know there are many posts around "The server is not operational" error, but my specific question is more around if this error could be related to the VPN connection while I am on another domain?  While connected to VPN I am able to use Softerra LDAP Browser to browse the AD using the same path and credentials I am using in the code snippet above. Off VPN I am able to access my local AD without error using same code about (albeit different path and credentials).

Note: I believe the AuthenticationTypes should be Secure based on the port, but I tried all the options with same result.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This doesn't answer your question, but your exceptin indicates this code is in a view. Don't do that - keep your logic in the controller or a service layer of some sort.

Comment: The port indicates a secure connection indeed. Did you try using the ip instead of the domain name? as you are not on the domain it might have some issues resolving the domain name.

Comment: @DavidG Agreed. Just stubbing out a snippet that will eventually reside in controller.

Comment: @StfBln Tried ip w/ same results.

Comment: Multiple posts online are mentioning LDAP through VPN is an issue. Check the following which might somewhat provide more information: https://forum.fortinet.com/tm.aspx?m=125136 and http://serverfault.com/questions/485909/how-can-i-access-a-local-area-ldap-through-a-vpn

Answer (score 1):

I've seen a similar issue -minus the VPN- resolved by adding a static hosts entry mapped to the target domain on the originating server.  in your case, on the serer running the code: x.x.x.x domain.com